# NameError with RDiscount

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed the RDiscount gem to my project.

When I try to put the following in my application_helper.rb:

```
RDiscount.new(text).to_html
```

I get

```
NameError:  
uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper::RDiscount
```

In the irb I can get RDiscount working after requiring it, but I can't get it to function anywhere in my project. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Have you put `gem "rdiscount"` in your Gemfile, updated and restarted your server? I got this error when I forgot to restart the server.